# Stop an element from appearing above fullscreen video

Tags: video, z-index, fullscreen

I've seen plenty of answers on how to make a div appear *over* a fullscreen video, but I'm having the opposite problem: I can't get a section element to appear *under* the fullscreen video.

The video is in the second section, hit play and fullscreen to see the error: http://arc.karo.com/

This occurs in Safari and Chrome, but not Microsoft Edge or Firefox, so it must be a webkit issue. I'm open to any idea to fix this: JS, CSS or otherwise. It looks like an issue with z-index, but playing with those values has no effect.

[image]

Comment: Not reproduceable here, please upload a screenshot from what you are seeing.

Comment: Added a screenshot. You can see the video tucked below the hero section

Comment: Hm, no clue why it dont work to give the player higher z-index. But when removing z-index:10 from your <header> element, the player is in foreground...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's the `clip-path` property that messes things up. I was able to solve it by toggling a class that gets rid of all clip-paths whenever fullscreen is clicked. This is specific to the Brightcove Player, but could be applied to any embedded video with some simple edits.

HTML:

```
<video
    id="bc-player" 
    data-video-id="{{ entry.videoId }}"
    data-account="1098679119001" 
    data-player="rkZZRZTudz" 
    data-embed="default" 
    data-application-id 
    class="video-js" 
    controls 
    width="343" 
    height="192.94">
</video>
<script src="//players.brightcove.net/1098679119001/rkZZRZTudz_default/index.min.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  videojs('bc-player').ready(function(){
    var myPlayer = this;
    var myFunc = function(){
      var myPlayer = this;
      $('body').toggleClass('fullscreen-toggle');
    };
    myPlayer.on("fullscreenchange", myFunc);
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.fullscreen-toggle * {
  -webkit-clip-path: none !important;
  clip-path: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Would this be a webkit bug? Is there someone I should report it?